# How can we add wpform to custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I create custom theme and I am trying to create a contact form using wpform but for some reasons the form doesn't show on my page

here is a code from the custom theme

```
<?php 
    /* Template Name: CallUS*/
    get_header();?>

<section>
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-valign-middle-xs u-sheet-1">
        <h1>
          call us
        </h1>
        <img
          class="u-image u-image-default u-image-1 u-hidden-xs"
          src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/---1113.png"
          alt=""
          data-image-width="800"
          data-image-height="972"
        />
      </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

[and this picture from the form that I have created using wpform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOJGU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 01:**
You must have the_content() function in order to show page contents. I've edited your code so you can see how to do it:

```
<?php 
    /* Template Name: CallUS*/
    get_header();?>

<section>
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-valign-middle-xs u-sheet-1">
        <h1>
          call us
        </h1>
        <img
          class="u-image u-image-default u-image-1 u-hidden-xs"
          src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/---1113.png"
          alt=""
          data-image-width="800"
          data-image-height="972"
        />
       <?php
        while ( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();

            the_content();

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>
      </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Then you've to select **CallUS** Page Template from below page:
[image]

**Way 02:**
If you go to the WPForms from the menu then you can see the shortcode column on each row. it will be like `[wpforms id="123"]`

[image: WP form shortcode]

Copy your design shortcode from there and use that directly into your file like below:

```
<?php 
    /* Template Name: CallUS*/
    get_header();?>

<section>
      <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-valign-middle-xs u-sheet-1">
        <h1>
          call us
        </h1>
        <img
          class="u-image u-image-default u-image-1 u-hidden-xs"
          src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/---1113.png"
          alt=""
          data-image-width="800"
          data-image-height="972"
        />
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpforms id="3306"]');?>
      </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer();?>
```